# Possibility of identification of non trained item in Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

A machine learning model has been trained to recognize the name of Animals and Plants. If suppose an automobile name is given, is it possible to say that the given name doesn't belong to the category animals or plants. If possible, kindly mention the methodology or algorithm which achieves this scenario.

E.g. If 'Lion' or 'Coconut Tree' is given the model will be predicting either 'Animals' or 'Trees' category. If suppose, 'Audi' is given, is it possible to say that the given item belongs neither to  'Animals' or 'Plants'. (Note : I have heard that the machine learning model will try to fit into either one the category).

Comment: you can add third option (within data train) which is not animal and not tree

Comment: Thank you. But, is it possible to say without adding to training data ? i.e. since it is trained on Animals and Tree and when 'Audi' is given, it might no find much features matching to that so, is it possible that it says, it's neither a Plant or Animal.

Comment: you can try using Anomali Detection if you can't adding training data

Comment: @malioboro ,Be human.Original Poster is here to learn.

Comment: @RamaswamyM , just define a classification algorithm.

Comment: @quintumnia Thanks for your kind suggestion. I am a newbie to ML. Pardon my ignorance, if the question sounds silly :-)

Comment: @quintumnia Thanks for your kind suggestion. I am a newbie to ML. Pardon my ignorance, if the question sounds silly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classifier actually gives you a probability of item belonging to a category, unless you add a final layer or post-processing that translates those probabilities to one and zeros. So, you can define a certain confidence threshold for probabilities and if classifier does not output probabilities above the threshold then call the output undecided.

An "audi" can still have features that make network believe it is tree for example.